# How to choose colors in sequence while using Python turtle?

Tags: python, colors, turtle-graphics

I have the below Python program to draw a square design using colors listed below. The program is applying only the pink for all boxes, how do I make the syntax to repeat the colors in sequence listed below?

```
import turtle

def main():
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.hideturtle()
    t.speed(500)
    color = ["pink", "navy blue","red","forest green","cyan","magenta"]
    squaredesign(t,color)

def squaredesign(t,color):
    x = 100
    y = 100
    z = 1
    c = 0

    for i in range(10):

          t.up()
          t.goto(x,y)
          t.down()

          t.goto(x-x-x,y)
          t.goto(x-x-x,y-y-y)
          t.goto(x,y-y-y)
          t.goto(x,y)

          x+=-10
          y+=-10
          t.pencolor(color[c])

main()
```

Comment: t.pencolor(color[i])

Comment: Thank you.  It's working for first 6 squares and giving "index error: list index out of range".  How to repeat the color after the last color is picked?

Comment: how did you try to solve the problem ?

Comment: i replaced the variable and the boxes were drawn but it stopped after the 6 colors were used, so i used a while loop to reset c to zero but it didn't loop through.

Comment: if c == 4:
            c = 0
        else:
            c+=1

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the `cycle` function from `itertools` for this purpose:

```
from itertools import cycle
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

COLORS = ["pink", "navy blue", "red", "forest green", "cyan", "magenta"]

def main():
    t = Turtle(visible=False)
    t.speed('fastest')

    color_iter = cycle(COLORS)

    squaredesign(t, color_iter)

def squaredesign(t, color_iter):
    x = 100
    y = 100

    for _ in range(10):

        t.pencolor(next(color_iter))

        t.penup()
        t.goto(x, y)
        t.pendown()

        t.goto(x - x - x, y)
        t.goto(x - x - x, y - y - y)
        t.goto(x, y - y - y)
        t.goto(x, y)

        x -= 10
        y -= 10

screen = Screen()

main()

screen.mainloop()
```

It never runs out of colors as it just starts over from the beginning after it reaches the end.  The modulus operator (%) is another approach you can use to solve this problem:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

COLORS = ["pink", "navy blue", "red", "forest green", "cyan", "magenta"]

def main():
    t = Turtle(visible=False)
    t.speed('fastest')

    color_index = 0

    squaredesign(t, color_index)

def squaredesign(t, color_index):
    x = 100
    y = 100

    for _ in range(10):

        t.pencolor(COLORS[color_index])

        t.penup()
        t.goto(x, y)
        t.pendown()

        t.goto(x - x - x, y)
        t.goto(x - x - x, y - y - y)
        t.goto(x, y - y - y)
        t.goto(x, y)

        x -= 10
        y -= 10

        color_index = (color_index + 1) % len(COLORS)

screen = Screen()

main()

screen.mainloop()
```

Which avoids the additional import.